# Camera Sensor partially parsed/processed to improve framerate

Tags: android, performance, android-camera, android-sensors, frame-rate

I'm working on a project which ultimately uses an app to recognize spoken words via face recognition and gives feedback how good your pronunciation was.

I would like to know if there is a way to only partially get the data from the camera sensor (ROI) so not all pixels have to be parsed and processed to possibly improve framerates and lower the datastream.
I'm fairly new to android app dev, so I don't know if there is a way to call the sensor on this level or if such intervention on hardware specific elements can't be handeled by software methods.

So I would appreciate if there is anyone who could tell me if there is a way. Researching android docu didn't get me any results so far.

Thanks in advance and regards from Germany

Comment: So, basically you want a low-res/scaled down image from the camera to feed to your algorithm?

Comment: I don't want to scale down the whole picture(e.g. HD 1920*1080px). I would like to set it up that any image capture method is only passing a region of interest (ROI) from the sensor itself (to an e.g. algorithm, SurfaceView or method which saves the image), so the capture method doesn't have to run through all pixels (only passing the pixels ...456-644...*...234-321... of a 1920*1080 picture for example).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this isn't supported.

While the camera API allows for setting a level of digital zoom (for the deprecated android.hardware.Camera API) or an explicit crop region (on the current android.hardware.camera2 API), there's no guarantee that frame rate will increase when you select a smaller region.

This is because digital zoom is expected to be variable per-frame, and image sensors can generally not reconfigure their readout region that quickly.  So digital zoom / crop is implemented in the camera image processing pipeline instead, and the sensor always reads out the full frame.

Some lower-resolution output configurations may set the sensor to skipping/binning modes, which does increase the maximum frame rate by reducing the number of pixels read off the sensor, but you indicate you need full resolution on a small ROI, so this doesn't help you.

Comment: I sadly expected something in that direction, but thank you for your answer!